# Need help on css header float

Tags: html, css, css-float

When i do my web design, meet a problem when i need to do

[LEFT LOGO]  then  [TITLE(CENTER)] then [RIGHT LOGO]

The problem appear at RIGHT LOGO there, it doesn't align with LEFT LOGO.
The right logo is under the line of TITLE(CENTER)

here is my code sample, thanks:

```
<div class="navigation">
<div id="left">
    <a title="Multimedia" href="#">
        <img src="images/logo.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="title">Tutor Program</div>
<div id="right">
    <a href="#" title="Inspire and Innovate">
        <img src="images/tagline_alt.png"/>
    </a>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.navigation{
    height:auto;
    background-color:#666;
    width:85%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:800px;
}
#title{
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family:‘Arial Black’, Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#left {
    float: left;text-align:left;
    margin: auto;
}
#right {
    float: right;text-align:right;
    margin: auto;
}
a img { border: 0; }
```

Comment: Put the right logo before the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply move the right container above the left container check below

```
<div class="navigation">
   <div id="right">
    <a href="#" title="Inspire and Innovate">
      <img src="images/tagline_alt.png"/>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
    <a title="Multimedia" href="#">
       <img src="images/logo.png"/>
    </a>
   </div>
    <div id="title">Tutor Program</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing its work an another way i have some changes in style width depends of logo width. if it is not set in center then change the width %.

```
#title{
text-align:center;
margin: auto;
font-family:'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: #FFF;
width:59%;
float:left;
```

}

```
.clear {
clear:both;
margin:0px;
font-size:0px;
}
```

and add a div after the last div with class clear.

```
<div id="right"> .... </div> 
<div class="clear"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also display your divs as a `table` and `table-cells`, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="title">
        title
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        right
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.navigation > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.navigation div:nth-child(1) { 
    background: lightgray; 
}
.navigation div:nth-child(2) { 
    background: gray; 
    text-align: center; 
}
.navigation div:nth-child(3) { 
    background: lightgray; 
    text-align: right; 
}
```

Also check [the JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/BXWs5/)